# React console.log(i) print the previews result

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-lifecycle

With the code below - handleChange methos is used in form fields:

1. starting `i = 0`
2. with the first change
3. `i` should get updated with `i+1`
4. and `console.log(i)`  = **should be 1, but get 0**

- I tried to research the lifecycles and read a lot of posts, but couldn't understand how to fix it (tried to simplify the question).

Thanks

```
const [i, setI] = useState(0)

const handleChange = input => event => {
        setI(i + 1)
        console.log(i)
        }

<ChildFormComponent handleChange={handleChange}/>
```

Comment: Step #3 is wrong "i should get updated with i+1". It would be updated after the handler is already finished. You are logging current value of `i`. If you did `setI(i++)` you'd actually update the value though it is **not** recommended way in react.

Comment: Also since your state depends on the previous state value recommended way would be to use a callback form `setIt(i => i + 1)`

Comment: I'm trying to calculate `total_cost` and display it to the user - what's the right way to set something like that to update and then display the updated result?

I tried to update now to `setI(i => i + 1)` and it's still showing 0 after first change

Comment: State is updated after re-render. See this article for an explanation https://jonathanmadelaine.com/blog/state-it-dont-mutate-it

Comment: " I tried to update now to `setI(i => i + 1)` and it's still showing 0" yes because this is how state update works. I though this form would actually make it more clear to you why state updates are async. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: Thank you all, with all your help it  clarified it - I needed to add the useEffect conditionally to the value, as suggested.   I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `setI` function is async. I is not updated synchronously but asynchronously. If you want to log the new value of `i` use the `useEffect` hook and add `i` as its dependency.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(i)
}, [i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure on your `handleChange` declaration? Should it return function to you?

```
const handleChange = input => event => {
  setI(i + 1)
  console.log(i)
}
```

Could you try something similar to this instead

```
const handleChange = event => {
  setI(i => i + 1)
}
```

And don't worry about `console.log(i)` since the state updates are asynchronous.

You will get updated data in UI as others suggested in comments.

Comment: Those are not helping, the right way seems to be using the useEffect